# Compose Rows one after another wrapping around

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, staggered-gridview

Good day,

I am trying to achieve this in Compose but no luck. I have the composable (ItemActivity) ready that has to repeat N times, it is just a checkbox and a string -> I have a random string generator to simulate differente lengths for this.

[image]

This is my trying, but all I get is one below the other. I want as in this picture, no horizontal scroll, just wrapping ...

```
    LazyHorizontalStaggeredGrid(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        rows = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(activities),
        horizontalItemSpacing = 8.dp,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(activities) {
            ItemActivity(
                filterCheck = filterCheck,
                filterName = getRandomString()
            )
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Are you looking for a `FlowRow` type component? The base Compose libraries don't provide one AFAIK, but there are third party libraries that do. Or you could make one yourself on top of the `Layout` composable.

Comment: Yes, you need `FlowRow` and it's actually part of core compose library now: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow

Comment: @JanBína That's interesting! Is it in Compose Multiplatform too? I've been watching the release notes fairly closely, but I haven't seen a mention of that new API.

Comment: yeah it seems so, it's in the `commonMain` folder of `foundation-layout`: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/FlowLayout.kt;l=55?q=FlowRow

Comment: FlowRow works like a charm guys!